# Creating short-cut key using pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to create a short-cut key to switch between line chart and candlestick chart on tradingview. Is it possible to do this using pinescript? I am open to other work-around that may not require the use of pinescript.

I am using pinescript v5

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create shortcuts yourself.

The available shortcuts are listed here: https://www.tradingview.com/support/shortcuts/